# Can't fetch Firbase webapp database in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, es6-modules

I can't fetch the data from firebase database.I have used these code to import the firebase database below:
    `import  firebase from 'firebase/app'
    import    "firebase/database";
     const firebaseDB = firebase.database();
      const firebaseArticle = firebaseDB.ref('articles')
      const firebaseTeams = firebaseDB.ref('teams')
      const firebaseVideos = firebaseDB.ref('videos')`

And in another file where I want to fetch the data from firebase i used these codes
[image]`UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    firebaseArticle
      .limitToFirst(3)
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const news = [];
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
          news.push({
            ...childSnapshot.val(),
            id: childSnapshot.key,
          });
        });
        this.setState({
          news
        });
      });`

I am getting these error messages in the console. Looks like I've got problems in lifecycles even though I've used UNSAFE_lifecyclename which they recommended. What should I do now to fetch data from firebase? & How can I get rid of these warnings?
Thanks

Comment: try to use componentDidMount instead of UNSAFE_componentWillMount

Comment: here is a good article for react lifecycle methods https://medium.com/@mksglu/react-16-3-lifecycle-methods-7ac4e2f2024a

Comment: Most of these warnings are coming from React extension for chrome, it won't be there in production, check with disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `componentDidMount`, like so:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  firebaseArticle
    .limitToFirst(3)
    .once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const news = [];
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        news.push({
          ...childSnapshot.val(),
          id: childSnapshot.key,
        });
      });
      this.setState({
        news
      });
    });
}
```